# operator new[] extremely slow on MSVC debug

Tags: c++, memory-management, new-operator

In my application startup there is a quite little allocation of memory for a 3-ary pointer structure.

```
#define N_1 1024
#define N_2 32
#define N_3 1024

#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

typedef uint16_t counts;
typedef counts * spectra;
typedef spectra * line;
typedef line * pline;
typedef pline * cube;

void foo()
{
    cube cb = new pline[N_3];

    for (int n3 = 0; n3 < N_3; n3++)
    {
        boost::posix_time::ptime tic = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();

        line ln = new spectra[N_2];

        for (int n2 = 0; n2 < N_2; n2++)            
        {
            ln[n2] = new counts[N_1]();
        }

        cb[n3] = &(ln);

        boost::posix_time::ptime toc = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time();
        boost::posix_time::time_duration dur = toc - tic;
        std::cout << n3 << " line allocated in " << dur.total_microseconds() << " us\n";
    }
}
```

So we got an allocation of `sizeof(counts)*N_1*N_2*N_3` = `2*1024*1024*32` bytes, resulting in `64 MB` on the heap.

Problem is, building in *Visual Studio DEBUG* mode only, about the enormous time consumed during `foo()` execution.
In particular, this is a part of a strange (afaik) log:

> 0 line allocated in 0 us
>
> 1 line allocated in 0 us
>
> .........................
>
> 104 line allocated in 0 us
>
> 105 line allocated in **1000002** us
>
> 106 line allocated in 0 us
>
> .........................

In *Release* mode, everything's running smooth. Any insight ?

**EDIT:**

Since most of you pointed out my wrong usage of `boost::posix_time::second_clock`, now replaced by `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock`, I'd like to highlight the fact that the real issue is on `new[]` performance while debugging, not on which is the best *tic-toc* tool.

Comment: I suspect adding [`_NO_DEBUG_HEAP`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/03/03/make-debugging-faster-with-visual-studio/) to the environment var settings of your project's debug startup configuration may produce more desirable results. Still, the debug vs release versions of the runtime suballocator are likely much more pedantic in debug vs release mode.

Comment: is this while running inside visual studio or on console? But debug mode inserts some more checks (like boundary checks) to the compilation. So `new` does more while in debug mode than in release.

Comment: Not too familiar with Boost, but it looks like your timing only has 1-second resolution.

Comment: It's name literally says so, **second_clock**.

Comment: Please don't hide pointers behind typedefs. It makes your code hard to read unless you're a Java programmer, in which case it makes your code highly non-idiomatic and leak-prone.

Comment: Pete Becker what are you going to suggest instead?

Answer (score 5):

You're using `boost::posix_time::second_clock` which only ticks once every second. The time measurement you do is thus either zero seconds or 1 second (or more, but that's unlikely). Printing a measurement of 1s as us gives you your output.

Comment: This is not the problem. Using a `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock` produces durations of 1001 - 1002 microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to celebrate the coming new year? It may happen that you will be too tired and won't stay awake to raise a glass of wine right at 00:00. When you wake up the next day, will it be fair to claim that you have slept for one full year (since you fell asleep in 2016 and woke up in 2017)?

The same happens with your clock that has a resolution of one second. If an operation starts executing close enough to the accurate second boundary (e.g. at 10:23AM 45 seconds and 999 milliseconds) it will appear to have last for 1 second.

In a release build most of the time is spent on the "`cout <<  ...`" thing, and the rest of the program has a negligible chance of catching the instant of the incrementing second value. Using a debug (and therefore somewhat slower) version of the program increases the chances for such an event, as the slowdown of the memory allocation operations in a debug build is more than the slowdown of I/O operations.

---

**EDIT**

Note that usage of `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock` [doesn't guarantee microsecond resolution](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/date_time/posix_time.html):

> `ptime microsec_clock::local_time()`
>
> Get the local time using a sub second resolution clock. On Unix
>   systems this is implemented using GetTimeOfDay. On most Win32
>   platforms it is implemented using ftime. **Win32 systems often do not
>   achieve microsecond resolution via this API**. If higher resolution is
>   critical to your application test your platform to see the achieved
>   resolution.

Comment: It was really funny, but time flows anyhow, with or without my awkward *tic-toc* implementation ! Real issue is on `new []` overhead when `_DEBUG` is defined.

Comment: @PatrizioBertoni `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock` doesn't guarantee microsecond resolution. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, but I'm arguing on something else. See updated question.

Comment: @PatrizioBertoni I wrote my comment after seeing the updated question. My point is that in your setup `boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::local_time()` may be no different from `boost::posix_time::second_clock::local_time()`, and therefore the **1000000 us** number is not a correct measurement of the speed of `operator new[]`.